# List Property Setter

Tags: c#, list, encapsulation

When implementing a setter for a List property (in C#) is it a bad thing to write is as:

```
    private List<string> _TheList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> TheList
    {
        get { return _TheList; }
        set { _TheList = value; }
    }
```

Should it not be written as:

```
    private List<string> _TheList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> TheList
    {
        get { return _TheList; }
        set { _TheList = new List<string>(value); }
    }
```

Up until today I have typically used the former, but I recently found some code that was using the latter and it seemed that this is probably the correct way to implement this.

Won't using the former cause the TheList property to be changed when changes are made to the external list that gets assigned to it. For example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hello");

var c = new someClass();
c.TheList = list;
```

Using the former won't the following code break the encapsulation of TheList:

```
list.Clear();
```

Now c.TheList is also empty, which may not be what we wanted. However, using the latter approach, c.TheList would not be cleared.

Comment: No, second solution isn't correct. Use first solution and if you want to set a copy instead of a reference - write c.TheList = new List<string>(list);

Comment: That depends on your ownership semantics. Some callers might expect to be able to set the list and still update it "from the outside". Whichever path you take, be sure to document it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. I'm glad I didn't start using the second approach without checking first. It appears the consensus is to not provide a setter (in most cases) or to at least make it protected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Collection properties should be readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx).

[Your property should expose a `Collection<T>`, not a `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx).

**EDIT**: Explanations:

If other code copies a reference to the list (eg, `var list = Thingy.TheList`), it can get messed up if you set the property to a different list.  (It will end up holding an orphan)
In general, there are very few reasons to allow people to make a property point to a different collection instance.

Using `Collection<T>` instead of `List<T>` allows you to intercept changes to the collection and add validation or maintain parent fields.  (by inheriting `Collection<T>` and overriding `InsertItem` and other methods) You can even add such logic after shippinga library without breaking calling code.

Comment: Or expose as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `List<T>` has an AsReadOnly() method to make it easy to do the return.

Comment: Do you know of any good articles that explains why those two principles hold true? I don't fully see what is wrong with having a writeable List<T> as a property.

Comment: Great links! I've never used any Code Analysis tools before. Is this as simple as installing/running fxCop? Frankly I'd be afraid to run fxCop on the current project I'm working on :P

Comment: @What: Yes, it is.  Beware that it will give hundreds if not thousands of warnings when first run on a non-trivial existing project.

Comment: @SLaks I know this post is a bit old, but was wondering if it is fine to inherit from IList<T>.  IList<T> inherits directly from ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, and IEnumerable.  I am planning on making use of WCF for serialization so inheritence, while important at the OO layer level, needs to be flattened at the messaging level to maintain performance.  Regardless, is there any concern to using IList<T> has the parent?  I would assume not as in this case one would write all of their own method functionality.  IList<T> would appear to simplify the inheritance reference.

Comment: @ZackJannsen: `IList<T>` is an _interface_.  There is nothing wrong with implementing an interface.  (note that `Collection<T>` will do most of the work for you)  The problem with inheriting from the `List<T>` class is that its design and implementation make it impossible to customize its behavior in a derived class. (there is nothing you can override)

Answer (score 6):

I believe since a list is a reference object, all you need to do is get the reference.  So:

```
   private List<string> _TheList = new List<string>();
public List<string> TheList
{
    get { return _TheList; }
}
```

Once you have the reference, and make changes to the collection, you're changing _TheList

Answer (score 3):

It completely depends on how you want your property to operate. If you want a copy, make a copy. Otherwise, don't. Often times properties like that won't expose a setter at all, since replacing the entire list isn't a desired action for that case.

Of course, using your second method is potentially a performance pitfall, since the property syntax hides the fact that you're completely copying and creating a new list every time you use the setter.

Answer (score 0):

First off, both are somewhat incorrect. Public properties should really be exposed as IList since List is implementation specific (fxcop will actually warn you when using List as a public property).

Second, if possible I would have the setter be private.  Using the getter a user can still Add/Remove/Clear/etc. but simplifies the issues you raised in your question.

Comment: I typically will use IList, but since in the second approach we're explicitly using new List() I figured it made more sense to define the property as such.

Comment: I just realized that IList<T> doesn't include the method AddRange, which I want. Only the List<T> implementation contains this method. So why wouldn't I expose this property as a List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a universal answer to your question. The behavior you describe may or may not be what you want.

In general I agree with SLaks that it is cleaner to keep the collections properties read-only but it all depends

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood correctly. But i am doing it like that:

```
c.TheList = list.ToArray().ToList();
```

Comment: So you have a list that you convert to an array then back to a list? As has already been agreed upon by many commenters, you typically don't want to expose the list through a setter, which you would have to in order to do what you've proposed. Can you explain more what you're proposing here.